# SOLR loses some of the words from the fields with CONCAT function query - how to make it process all words?

Tags: function, solr, concatenation

I have a SOLR document:

```
{
    "id": "Test1",
    "MyInt": 100500,
    "FirstString": ["Test First String"],
    "SecondString": ["Test Second String"]
}
```

managed-schema for this core is:

```
...
  <field name="MyInt" type="plong" /> 
  <field name="FirstString" type="text_general" /> 
  <field name="SecondString" type="text_general" /> 
...
```

Type "text_general" - this is for the correct search.

I need to get concat of two text fields in the /select.
I create such a request:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/testcore/select?q=*:*&fl=Result:concat(FirstString,';',SecondString)
```

Expect to see in results sometstrong texthing like:

```
Result:"Test First String;Test Second String"
```

But in fact, SOLR removes part of the words and leaves only 1 word from each field. Perhaps the most important thing to look for:

```
Result:"First;Second"
```

Do not offer me to change wt=json to wt=csv in /select, I know about this feature, but in this case it does not fit.

Please advise what is the reason for such strange behavior of SALS?

Perhaps this is due to the fact that the data is stored in type="text_general" fields with multiValued=true? I did an experiment with type="string" fields - the problem repeats.

I can’t understand how to make SOLR take all words from the text_general fields in concat function query?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption about this being because of using the `text_general` field type is correct; only the first token will be returned from the field when you're using `concat`. However, you're saying that it doesn't work when using a `string` field either - that's false. When using a `string` field type (i.e. no processing happening and the text being stored verbatim as a single token), the behaviour is as you're requesting:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":4,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "fl":"FirstField_string, LastField_string, Result:concat(FirstField_string,';',LastField_string)",
      "_":"1581267948122"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "FirstField_string":"Test First String",
        "LastField_string":"Test Second String",
        "Result":"Test First String;Test Second String"}]
  }}
```

The field name changes are just because I experimented with your original field names. This requires the field to be `multiValued="false"`.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand what the problem was and how to solve it!